# Application not handle <Universal Links>

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-universal-links

I have some trouble with universal links, and I can't understand why my app not handle Universal Link.
Application based on SwiftUI but I use UIkit for developing

```
@main
struct iOSApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {

            WrapperUIVC_Hello().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onOpenURL { url in
// don't work
                    print("Universal link \(url)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and this code also don't work

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, let url = userActivity.webpageURL, let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
            print("Universal Link trouble")
            return false
        }
        for queryItem in components.queryItems ?? [] {
            print("Universal link components \(queryItem)")
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

also inside entitlements, I use:

```
applinks:example.com
webcredentials:example.com
```

My file is hosted like "example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association & example.com/apple-app-site-association:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "U678YHJU89.com.example",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "#": "society/lettings"
                    },
                    {
                        "#": "society/lettings/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "#": "society/acquisitions"
                    },
                    {
                        "#": "society/acquisitions/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "U678YHJU89.com.example"
        ]
    }
}
```

For testing my file I use:
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox
And all tests was passed -

```
"This domain validates, JSON format is valid, and the Bundle and Apple App Prefixes match (if provided).
Below you’ll find a list of tests that were run and a copy of your apple-app-site-association file:"
```

Also I use https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool:
Apple say to me another msg

```
Action required
Could not extract required information for application links. Learn how to implement the recommended Universal Links.
Error cannot parse app site association
```

But I check syntax all look well, also I use additional web tools, and can say that route to AASA not have **redirection** and **status code 200**

Also I tried user modification like **?mode=developer** etc. but in my case it did not worked.
I did all testing functionality locally in  mode.

If I use command in CMD(for .well-known & and without) **- curl -v 'example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association**' all look well

```
* Connected to example.com (myip) port 80 (#0)
> GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 17:24:18 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

if I use command **- curl -v 'https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association**, content type will next

```
content-type: application/json
```

Where do I have mistakes, and what I can use for additional debugging?

Comment: In the current AASA format (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains), the `appIDs` property (note also the `s` at the end) is an array. (Perhaps you have confused this with the earlier AASA format, where there was indeed an `appId` property, but along with `paths` and not `components`)?

Comment: @StephanSchlecht, thank you for your observing, you are my hero)), right now all for fine, exists a new problem from API validation<Error no apps associated with URL> but I guess this is because the file has wrong TeamID. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used old standard of syntax for AASA file, thank you [Stephen Schlecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2331445/stephan-schlecht) for observing